# List<dynamic>', but got one of type 'Null' Server Handler: errorExpected a value of type 'List<dynamic>'?

Tags: mysql, flutter, dart, error-handling

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AbcC.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Zx9i.png)Hi i have a question I've got this error
**Expected a value of type 'List', but got one of type 'Null'
Server Handler: errorExpected a value of type 'List', but got one of type 'Null'**
can someone help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9OiY.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yv1Ee.png)

Comment: can you add some code where the problem is happening so we can help you ?

Comment: ive send it to answers

Answer (score 0):

In your model class you will have different datatypes check if any variable getting `null`value or not. Also check your API response for example.

`json response`

```
{
  "student_name":"sample_name",
  "roll_no": 1,
  "address": "address",
  "mob_no":null,

}
```

In the above situation you will get exception because in your model class you
defined the `mob_no` as `int` so to handle this situation you need to add `dynamic or ?` variable for example `dynamic mob_no or int?`. In some cases it might possible you will get null values on that conditon you have to use `?`. because if your defining `variable` as `String` or `int` it means it should not be null.

Comment: ive checked via postman and all data in json response shows

Comment: Your getting null somewhere please check your json response and one more thing check your json response is correctly parsed or not

Comment: all json response go correctly can I send You code to see ?

Comment: Send me your response and your model class